# Make sure TextBox is an integer between 0 and 20. If not make the user re enter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I make sure the input is an Integer between 0 and 20 and if not, clear the textbox and make the user re-enter. I keep trying to do this but the program crashes and I can't figure it out.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    For Each ch As Char In TextBox2.Text
        Dim input As String
        input = TextBox2.Text()
        Dim a As Integer = 0
        a = Integer.Parse(input)
        If Not Char.IsDigit(ch) Or a > 20  Or a < 0 Then
        tt.Show("Please Enter Valid Numbers Only", TextBox2, New Point(0, -40), 2)
        TextBox2.Clear()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To whoever down-voted this question, why not explain yourself?  Is this not a legitimate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Validating` event, and then set `e.Cancel` to true if their input is not valid.  Here is what I would do:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Validating
    If (Not New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]{1,}[0-9]{0,}$").IsMatch(TextBox2.Text) OrElse
        CInt(TextBox2.Text) < 0 OrElse CInt(TextBox2.Text) > 20) Then

        MsgBox("Please Enter Valid Numbers Only")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It validates the expression using a regular expression to first make sure it's a natural number, then, assuming it is, it makes sure it's in your range (0 to 20).  If not, it presents the message to the user and cancels the validation of the field.

Comment: I am completely new to this how do I do this? Any guidance is sincerely appreciated

Comment: So I need to somehow call this event within my Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged method?

Comment: No, you would use this event handler in place of the text changed event handler.  I.e. delete what you have and paste my code instead.

Comment: In other words, delete your entire `TextBox2_TextChanged` Sub, and use the Sub I provided instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub tb_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles tb.Validating
 Dim result As Boolean = True
 Dim int As Integer
 'make sure it a number
 If Integer.TryParse(tb.Text, int) Then
  If (int < 0 OrElse int > 20) Then
    Dim tt As New ToolTip
    tt.Show("Number must be 0 - 20", Me, tb.Left, tb.Top)
    result = True
  Else
    result = False
  End If
 End If
 e.Cancel = result
End Sub
```

Comment: If the input is not a number, the validation will succeed.

Comment: Even after your edits, it's still the case that if the input is not a number, the validation will succeed.

Comment: No it won't the boolean is set to true, which means the validation must succeed inside the Tryparse condition.

Comment: you have no "else" on the try-parse, so if it doesn't parse, then the validation will be true.

Comment: Did you try your code?  Try entering "aa" and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I was wrong, it does fail validation, but without any message.  The cursor just gets stuck in the textbox.